# gulp command not working on laravel Elixir on windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, netbeans, gulp

I was trying to run the gulp command in the windows command promptafter installing node_modules in my laravel installation but it came back with this error in my windows command prompt :-

'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I was trying to use Lavarel Elixir and as in the Laracast videos I was trying to get the gulp command working on my command prompt but it shows

I installed node_modules using the below command

npm install --no-bin-links

it installed all the files

I am using Netbeans as my IDE and it is showing an error in the node_modules folder also , so I am unsure as to how to get this fixed and Working

[image]

My Work Environment is
Apache through MAMP
OS :- Windows 10
IDE :- Netbeans

Thanking you in anticipation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to run `gulp` you need to install the gulp command line interface globally like so: `npm install -g gulp-cli`. Afterwards you need to add a gulpfile.js where you would configure your builds/tasks. For more information check out the official "Getting started" guide and the docs on gulp: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: Laravel has a file named gulpfile.js inbuilt so do I still need to add the file and from where in the system should I run the command line ? From the current project folder or the system 32 folder and should i run this in cmd as administrator?

Comment: After you run `npm install -g gulp-cli` this will install the gulp command line interface in a place where it is globally accessible. After installing it you should run open a command prompt, navigate to the folder where your gulpfile.js is located and run `gulp` from there.

Comment: i tried that but I am getting the error which I have updated now in my question ..

Comment: This means that the dependencies, defined in the `package.json` file have not been installed. I guess they are located in the same folder as the the gulpfile. To install those dependencies you need to run `npm install` and a new node_modules folder will be created where they will be installed.

Comment: yes that is created but with some errors as I showed in the screenshot in the question but still the gulp command does not work

Comment: try removing the node_modules folder and running a pure `npm install` again. If there are any errors during the install please post them as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115342/discussion-between-dhaval-chheda-and-vasil).